# Call Automatically Disconnects When Calling

Tags: calls, 5.1-lollipop, dialer-codes

I have a **android tablet with android 5.1 lollipop** in which I have an **airtel number**.

When I call someone using my number (not WhatsApp just normal call),  sometimes it shows "**Dialling**" and then automatically call ends in 1-2 seconds. Sometimes, it directly disconnects in 1-2 seconds.

Last thing I remember was that I was playing with some of the dial codes of Android. From then this problem started. Before that, I was able to make calls with the SIM which I have now & also with my old SIM

Answer (score 1):

So this is weird, but I realised that I accidentally dialled `*31#` and the problem started. Now, I dialled `#31#` and I am able to call.

For information on USSD/MMI Codes see this [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data)